# Migrating from .bash_aliases to ~/.ssh/config

Tags: parsing, ssh, vi, bash

This is my first post here, so please bear with me...

I have discovered the amazing powers of .ssh/config after having fully configured my .bash_aliases file, and as I'm pretty lame with programming, I was looking for a nice way to parse the connection details from the bash_aliases file into the ~/.ssh/config file.

So, going into details, my bash_aliases looks like this:

```
alias serverA='ssh -i ~/.ssh/serverA.key -o $SRVR_ALV user@serverAhostname'
alias serverB='ssh -i ~/.ssh/serverB.key -o $SRVR_ALV user@serverBhostname'
....
```

Where I have defined a variable for ServerAliveInterval in $SRVR_ALV.

My intention is to parse that entry into this and in the meantime get rid of that ugly variable

```
Host serverA
HostName serverAhostname
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/serverA.key

Host serverB
.....
```

What do you think is the best way to perform this? I was looking for a nice bash script, or perhaps using vi capabilities.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about some Perl?

```
perl -ne "/^alias (.*)='ssh -i (.*) -o (.*) (.*)\@(.*)'/ and 
    print qq{Host \$1\nHostName \$5\nIdentityFile \$2\n\n}" < \
 ~/.bash_aliases
```

If you like what you see, redirect it to append to `>> ~/.ssh/config`

**[Update]** - an explanation for the non-Perl user as to what's going on:

`perl -ne`: `-e` means, *'The next argument is the script to (**e**)xecute'*.
-n`means, '*run the given script once per line*' - so`-ne`can sort-of 
emulate`sed`.

The perl code:

```perl
/^alias (.*)='ssh -i (.*) -o (.*) (.*)\@(.*)'/ and 
print qq{Host \$1\nHostName \$5\nIdentityFile \$2\n\n}
```

reads: for only the lines that match the regexp `/^alias ../`, print a string (`qq{...}` is that same as `"..."` in Perl), and the interpolated variables `"\$1"`, `"\$4"` etc are the result of what was captured in the regexp.

`perl -ne` expects *input*, which comes from `< ~/.bash_aliases`.

Comment: I have just seen the notification on mail and had to check it out. I worked like a charm, now I'll have to analyze the script and adjust it a little bit to add a "User" line for each host.
Thanks for the prompt response!!!!

Comment: @Ichikata - Not much to analyze, but I left you an explanation in case it helps.